# Help me understand this simple io redirection in bash from ABS guide

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell

```
exec 3>&1                           # Save current "value" of stdout.  
ls -l 2>&1 >&3 3>&- | grep bad 3>&- # Close fd 3 for 'grep' (but not 'ls').  
#              ^^^^   ^^^^
exec 3>&-                           # Now close it for the remainder of the script.
```

I get the 3rd line where fd 3 is being closed.

**Doubts:** 1st line redirects fd 3 to stdout, globally... right?
**Questions:** What's happening on the 2nd line? Please provide a verbose explanation if possible.

Comment: Although one can do complicated tricks with additional descriptors in *sh, whether this should be done to the poor schlub who has to read it next (e.g. you) is less certain.

Comment: @msw  I was looking at your profile and you seem to have very good knowledge about Linux/UNIX shell etc. I respect you for that, but I do not appreciate you calling me a schlub. If you cannot help, please keep your wisecracks to yourself.

Comment: I am also the poor schlub who often has to re-read my own code at a later date. I'm sorry you took my comment personally, as it was generic, intented to be somewhat self-deprecating, and most certainly **not** intended to insult. Much of my profile is fiction, aside from me being around too long.

Comment: @msw, No worries. I saw the dictionary meaning of schlub and did not like it. Sorry for jumping to conclusion. I respect you for all the knowledge you have. Thanks for commenting/responding. Best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably the best [Redirection Tutorial](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial) I've found.  Whenever I see some funky redirection going on, I refer to this to help me through it.

Comment: Very informative article !! I read the tutorial and did the analysis. Here is what I got: For ls: 0 to terminal, 1 to terminal, 2 to pipe. For grep: 0 to pipe, 1 to terminal, 2 to terminal. Right ?

Answer (score 3):

Redirections are processed outer command to inner command, and within a command from left to right. Therefore, `ls -l 2>&1 >&3 3>&-` initially gets stdout to the pipe. Then, stderr is redirected to the pipe, stdout becomes the original stdout (unpiped) and the extra fd is closed. So the regular output of `ls -l` remains unchanged, the lines of the error output that contain "bad" are sent to stdout and the rest of the error output is discarded.

Comment: Thanks but:
How does this `exec 3>&1` save current value of stdout?
1st line assigns fd 3 to fd 1 and then in the second line fd 1 is assigned to fd 3 ? What does that mean ? I don't get it.
why close fd 3 twice in second line ?

Comment: fd 3 is closed twice because each of the two new processes has its own copy

Comment: I read the tutorial and did the analysis. Here is what I got: For ls: 0 to terminal, 1 to terminal, 2 to pipe. For grep: 0 to pipe, 1 to terminal, 2 to terminal. Right ?